# How to store multiple networkx graphs in one file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, networkx

What is the best way to store multiple networkx graphs in one file? [This](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html) page shows various ways to store one graph, but not multiple. Is there a way to do this easily in e.g. a csv file? My goal is to store randomly generated graphs to do some analysis afterwards.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to convert the graphs into a list of dictionaries, which can be pickled:

```
import pickle
import networkx as nx

# dummy graphs
G = nx.complete_graph(4)
H = nx.complete_graph(5)
I = nx.complete_graph(6)


def store_as_list_of_dicts(filename, *graphs):

    list_of_dicts = [nx.to_dict_of_dicts(graph) for graph in graphs]

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(list_of_dicts, f)
    

def load_list_of_dicts(filename, create_using=nx.Graph):
    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        list_of_dicts = pickle.load(f)
    
    graphs = [create_using(graph) for graph in list_of_dicts]
    
    return graphs


store_as_list_of_dicts('test.pkl', G,H,I)

graphs = load_list_of_dicts('test.pkl')
```

alternative graph constructors:

```
graphs = load_list_of_dicts('test.pkl', create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)
```